# how to match multiple words in python

Tags: python, regex

i'm looping through strings in the list "titles" and i want to print the string which word matches in "keywords_to_match":

```py
# import re
titles = ['walk to new zealand' , 'fly to mars' , 'drive to murica']
keywords_to_match = re.compile(r'(new zealand)?(mars)?(murica)')
for title in titles:
    # if any of words inside keywords_to_match are matched print title
    if keywords_to_match.search(title.lower()):
        print(title)
        # only prints "drive to murica"
```

this only prints "drive to murica" but i expect it to print all 3 of the strings inside "titles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```py
keywords_to_match = re.compile(r'\b(?:new zealand|mars|murica)\b')
```

I'm not sure you need a regex in your case. You can simply do:

```py
titles = ['walk to new zealand', 'fly to mars', 'drive to murica']
[t for t in titles if any(k in t for k in keywords)]
```

Comment: This doesn't really match words, it matches strings. So it would give a false positive for "fly to marseille". A more robust solution would be `r'\b(?:new zealand|mars|murica)\b'`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Good point, thanks.

Comment: `'|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keywords)` to build the regex fragment from a list

Comment: @ekhumoro could you elaborate i don't get why we have to use "?:()" with words that have space between them also why the "\b".

Comment: @SyedAfaq The `()` just groups the elements together, and the `?:` means that it doesn't capture anything. The `\b` matches a word boundary, which ensures that only *whole words* are matched. An equivalent pattern would be `r'\bnew zealand\b|\bmars\b|\bmurica\b'`.

Comment: @SyedAfaq All the explanations are in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

This also works

`keywords_to_match = re.compile(r'(new zealand|mars|murica)')`

Answer (score 1):

Use '|' in place of '?' to express OR relationships.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html